# Incluir campos html no panel title

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou utilizando bootstrap, e utilizo um panel title no início do formulário, que informa o nome do form que eu estou, porém no `right` gostaria de colocar no caso a data atual caso seja um novo cadastro, e a data gravada no banco caso seja uma edição, exemplo: `Data: 11/09/2018`.
Porém de toda a forma que eu tento, fica desconfigurado, se eu deixo somente o título que é `Pedido Fornecedores` fica certo, porém ao incluir a data ele passa pra linha de baixo. Tentei com `divs` porém também não deu certo, segue como estou tentando fazer:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:60px">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"> <div class="col-md-4">Pedido Fornecedor</div> <div class="col-md-8" style="text-align:right">Data</div><br /></h3>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Como podem ver, ele desce a linha, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2rdsvn38/2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso acontece pq o `<h3>` (na verdade qualquer elemento de título `H`), é um elemento com escopo de bloco, ou seja, ele ocupa 100% da largura do *container*, então como vc tem 2 elementos `<h3>` só pode ficar um por linha, e o segundo acaba ficando na linha de baixo.

Tirando isso vc tem alguns problemas semânticos, como `div`s dentro de um `H3`. O que não é correto...

Vc pode usar as classe `pull-right` e `pull-left` do próprio Bootstrap para alinhas esse textos. E construir o Grid da forma correta, usando um `.ROW` antes das `.COL-` conforma a documentação.

Veja o resultado da sua estrutura com esses ajustes.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
 <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:60px">
  <div class="panel-heading">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <h3 class="pull-left">título</h3>
     <h3 class="pull-right">data</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   Panel content
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Logicamente podem existir outras variações para contornar esse problema, mas eu fiz a opção que eu achei mais adequada, considerando a documentação do BS, o Grid e a semântica

Documentação oficial do Panel do Bootstrap 3: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#panels

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez.!!!

Comment: @marianac_costa sem problemas =)

Answer (score 3):

Como o Hugo disse é semanticamente incorreto utilizar `div` dentro de `h`, você pode estilizar o texto com **CSS** ao invés disto, mas, se for uma estrutura que tem que ser esta, você pode colocar uma **row** depois do **h3** e uma classe **text-right** do próprio bootstrap para alinhar o texto:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:60px">
   <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-7">Pedido Fornecedor</div>
           <div class="col-xs-5 text-right">Data</div>
        </div>
      </h3>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
   </div>
</div>
```